# Convert and eliminate duplicates in a JavaScript array to an ordinary object (containing arrays)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, duplicates, formatting

In JavaScript I have an array that has site data in it:

```
var sites = [ 
  ["Alabama", "Huntsville"], 
  ["Tennessee", "Nashville"], 
  ["Tennessee", "Memphis"], 
  {Tennessee, "Knoxville"], 
  ["New Mexico", "Los Alamos"], 
  ["New Mexico", "Santa Fe"] 
];
```

I need to convert it into an object such that the state names become the object keys and the city names are values in an array. This would also remove duplicate state names so the object would look like this:

```
var newSites = {
  Alabama: ["Huntsville"], 
  Tennessee: ["Nashville", "Memphis", "Knoxville"], 
  NewMexico: ["Los Alamos", "Santa Fe"] 
};
```

I've started programming something where I compare the state name in the array to the next state name in the array to combine like state names, but my logic is long and seems...messy.  (The state names are listed in alphabetical order, so my basic premise should work.  Also, the array will never have null or invalid values for either the state name or the city name.)

Is there an eloquent way to output such an object?

Comment: _"I've started programming something where I compare the state name in the array to the next state name in the array to combine like state names, but my logic is long and seems...messy."_ add it to the question. That's how this works and how messy code gets tidier.

Comment: I agree programming is messy and code is later cleaned up, but I also believe that asking if there is something straightforward to solve this is legitimate.  If it turns out there is something in lodash that takes my logic from 50 lines to 6 lines, I'm willing to put it out there...

Comment: That's not the point. StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Aluan, point taken.  I was trying to find out whether there was a function to explicitly do this.

Comment: There's no need for checking the next state name--create the object, if there's a key present for a state, append the city value, if there isn't, create the array, and append the city value. There are multiple ways this could be done--IMO starting w/ the easiest thing that works is best, then you can gussy it up with `reduce` or whatever if you're not already familiar with it. (Plus checking the "next" array value relies on ordering, which isn't necessary.)

Comment: Dave, that makes sense.  I was overthinking the logic.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dave Newton gave me the exact direction I needed (although I realize I could tighten this up even more). No more 50 lines of code!

```
var sites = [["Alabama", "Huntsville"], ["Tennessee", "Nashville"], ["Tennessee", "Memphis"], ["Tennessee", "Knoxville"],["New Mexico", "Los Alamos"], ["New Mexico", "Santa Fe"]];

var obj = {};
for (let x= 0; x < sites.length; x++) {
  let siteState =  sites[x][0];
  obj[siteState] = [];
}
for (let x= 0; x < sites.length; x++) {
  let siteState =  sites[x][0];
  let siteCity = sites[x][1];
  obj[siteState].push(siteCity);
}
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Glad you worked it out :) The only thing I'd change is doing only a single loop, and maybe destructuring each entry, e.g., `const [state, city] = sites[x]`, but these are relatively minor points. I almost always start with "get it working" then move to "making it righter"; it's just a matter of how many steps can be skipped, which just comes with time and experience.